# how to fix 'Cannot create an instance of class com.example.todolist.ui.task.TaskViewModel'

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

TasksFragment.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class TasksFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_tasks) {

private val taskViewModel: TaskViewModel by viewModels()

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val binding = FragmentTasksBinding.bind(view)
    val tasksAdapter = TasksAdapter()

    binding.recyclerViewTasks.apply {
        adapter = tasksAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        setHasFixedSize(true)
    }

    taskViewModel.tasks.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{
        tasksAdapter.submitList(it)
    })

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_tasks,menu)

    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search)
    val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView

    searchView.OnQueryTextChanged{
        taskViewModel.searchQuery.value = it
    }
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when(item.itemId){
        R.id.sort_by_name -> {
            taskViewModel.sortOrder.value = SortOrder.BY_NAME
            true
        }

        R.id.sort_by_date -> {
            taskViewModel.sortOrder.value = SortOrder.BY_DATE

            true
        }

        R.id.hide_items -> {
            item.isChecked = !item.isChecked
            taskViewModel.hideComplited.value = item.isChecked
            true
        }

        R.id.delete_all_items -> {
            true
        }
        else -> {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)}
    }
}
}
```

TaskViewModel.kt

```
class TaskViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val taskDao: TaskDao
): ViewModel() {

val searchQuery = MutableStateFlow("")
val sortOrder = MutableStateFlow(SortOrder.BY_DATE)
val hideComplited = MutableStateFlow(false)
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
private val taskFlow = combine(
    searchQuery,
    sortOrder,
    hideComplited){
    query,sortorder,hidecomplited ->
    Triple(query,sortorder,hidecomplited)
}
    .flatMapLatest {(query,sortorder,hidecomplicated) ->
    taskDao.getTasks(query,sortorder,hidecomplicated)
}
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
val tasks = taskFlow.asLiveData()
}

enum class SortOrder{ BY_DATE,BY_NAME}
```

ToDoApplication.kt

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class TodoApplication: Application() {
}
```

Logcat

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.todolist/com.example.todolist.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.todolist.ui.task.TaskViewModel
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6205)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.todolist.ui.task.TaskViewModel
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
at androidx.hilt.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:81)
at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:69)
at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:84)
at
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:111)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
at com.example.todolist.ui.task.TasksFragment.getTaskViewModel(TasksFragment.kt)
at com.example.todolist.ui.task.TasksFragment.onViewCreated(TasksFragment.kt:37)

Comment: Add `@HiltViewModel` annotation on VM .

Comment: if I add this annonation then it causes another error

Answer (score 0):

```
+ @HiltViewModel
class TaskViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val taskDao: TaskDao
): ViewModel() {
```

and add code

```
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun provideTaskDao(appDatabase: Db): TaskDao {
    return appDatabase.taskDao()
  }
```